# Ninject: Error activating string

Tags: c#, ninject

Im following a guide of how to setup SQLite. In the guide he uses code-behind like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     // Setup database
     var path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.sqlite"));
     _connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWP8(), path); 
}
```

Im trying to do the same thing but instead by following MVVM.
I thought his would be the way to go:

```
public override void Load()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.sqlite"));

    Bind<ISQLitePlatform>().To<SQLitePlatformWP8>().WithConstructorArgument("test.sqlite", path);
}
```

Ninject responds with:

```
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Activation path:

  4) Injection of dependency string into parameter databasePath of constructor

  3) Injection of dependency SQLiteConnection into parameter connection of constructor

  2) Injection of dependency ICarRepository into parameter carRepository of constructor

  1) Request for MainVModel
```

Any tips on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SQLiteConnection` needs the parameter and not the `SQLitePlatformWP8`.

So change your registration to:

```
Bind<SQLiteConnection>.ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("databasePath", path);
Bind<ISQLitePlatform>().To<SQLitePlatformWP8>();
```

Note: you need to use the correct paramter name `"databasePath"` which is definied in the `SQLiteConnection` class's [constructor](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/ecc19e91a94307d4e739c0f08884ff325c4810ae/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteConnection.cs#L94-L98).

Comment: Thank you! That worked and aswered my question. Unfortunatley I got anoter execption: 6) Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor
You already answered my question and I thank but maybe you know this one too =)

Comment: @Wranglerino post a new question. Also you will need to post the complete exception, since it states which parameter of which ctor / class is missing.

Comment: Thank you! New question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727682/ninject-injection-of-dependency-intptr-into-parameter-method-of-constructor