# Ninject: Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor

Tags: c#, ninject

I got help earlier with this question:

[Ninject: Error Activating Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723011/ninject-error-activating-string/27723071?noredirect=1#comment43864067_27723071)

@nemensv solved that one but I immediatley got a new exception regarding IntPtr. (see activation path below).

Been looking through the `ctor` [here](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/ecc19e91a94307d4e739c0f08884ff325c4810ae/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteConnection.cs#L94-L98)

Only place IntPtr shows up is in this line:

```
 Result r = Platform.SQLiteApi.Open(databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int)openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
```

How can I solve this using ninject?

Complete exception:

```
Activation path:

  6) Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor

  5) Injection of dependency BlobSerializerDelegate+SerializeDelegate into parameter serializeDelegate of constructor

  4) Injection of dependency IBlobSerializer into parameter serializer of constructor

  3) Injection of dependency SQLiteConnection into parameter connection of constructor

  2) Injection of dependency ICarRepository into parameter carRepository of constructor

  1) Request for MainViewModel
```

My code in Ninject:

```
 Bind<SQLiteConnection>()
                .ToSelf()
                .WithConstructorArgument("databasePath", path);
            Bind<ISQLitePlatform>().To<SQLitePlatformWinRT>();
            Bind<IBlobSerializer>().To<BlobSerializerDelegate>();
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

This worked for me:

`Bind<SQLiteConnection>().ToMethod(ctx => new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWP8(), path))`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ninject states it can't created an `BlobSerializerDelegate` because it doesn't know how to instanciated a `BlobSerializerDelegate+SerializeDelegate`. You either need to tell ninject how to created `BlobSerializerDelegate` - if that's even necessary - or tell it how to instanciate the `SQLiteConnection`.
I think for the given situtation the `ToMethod` binding would be best:

```
Bind<SQLiteConnection>().ToMethod(ctx => new SQLiteConnection(...));
```

The `ToMethod` action should just `new` the SQLiteConnection as you would without a DI container.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I do not understand. What are the "..." infront of New BlobSeriaLizerDelegate?
Up to that point I got this:
 Bind<SQLiteConnection>().ToMethod(path,"databasepath",

Comment: The parameters of the ctor are just "pseudo code". You put the parameters there that you want / which are defined by the constructor of `SQLiteConnection`.